# How to get a nice collapsible side bar menu with Bootstrap (yet another post about that)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I've seen countless examples of side bar navigation menus made with bootstrap, but none seem to be the way I'd like it.

I am looking for a couple features :

- Each menu item has an icon and text
- Collapsible : Display only the icons and top level menu items when collapsed
- Simple animation when collapsing/uncollapsing (sidebar comes over the content)
- Top level menu items and submenu items (hierarchy)

[This one is nice but doesn't collapse](http://bootstrap-layout.themekit.io/demo/sidebar-collapse.html)

[This one collapses (but not the way I want) but is missing icons + submenu items](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/)

[This one (2nd example) has the collapsing behaviour I want but is missing some other things (and the way to make the menu appear is ugly)](http://blog.codeply.com/2016/05/18/bootstrap-sidebar-responsive-examples/)

Is it possible to have all these features on a sidebar with Bootstrap + javascript?

Comment: Yes It's possible, did you try to do it?? You have a "nice one" and one that collapses, just compare and try to do one code from the two...

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to convert a sidebar on what you needed.

Please have a look at this **[`Codepen`](http://codepen.io/rastogi_saurav/pen/ObJepX)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a great start, thank you very much. I will try to add submenus support and improve the collapsing behaviour so it is not on a button click

Comment: @ibiza My pleasure!